# I cannot edit "your communities" list from within a Stack Overflow Team page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

I belong to a Stack Overflow Team. When I am in there, I cannot edit my communities list:

> [image]

I get an error:

> Something bad happened; please try again

However, I am able to do so if I am in any other site. For example, this I did from the Spanish.SE site:

> [image]

Comment: Can repro. The request is returning [418 status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCufo.png) with [suspicious request preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEWgt.png)

Comment: Animated images are so ... ugh

Comment: @JonH Speak for yourself. I collect these images and display them in my browser so anyone passing by will consider me unquestionably tasked and suitably busy.

Comment: Why is `418 - I'm a teapot` returned :D

Comment: @Lino it should be 'I'm a suspicious Teapot', but sadly no one's yet done the RFC

Comment: Wowah, I didn't even know you can do this!

Comment: @JonH Animated images are great for bug reports.  Especially when you're not on a programming site and everyone doesn't already have to deal with debugging.  Steps to reproduce, with pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be ready with our next release. Thank you for your report.